# Help with L'Hospital's Rule for $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\ln3x-\ln(x+7))$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Use L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\ln3x-\ln(x+7))$

$f(x)=\ln3x$
$f^{\prime}(x)=\dfrac{3}{3x}=\dfrac{1}{x}$

$g(x)=\ln(x+7)$
$g^{\prime}(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+7}$

So we have: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+7}$

How do you solve this problem, can you show? If I evaluate the limit now I will get $\infty - \infty$, And I will keep getting $x$ in the denominator, so I don't think I'm doing this correctly. Thanks.

My text has the answer $\ln3$

Comment: Actually the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+7}$ is $0-0=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\ln3x-\ln \left(x+7 \right)\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln \left(\frac{3x}{x+7} \right) \to \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln \left(\frac{3}{1} \right)=\ln 3 $$

Comment: +1 thanks, very clear. So how I was solving is completely incorrect?

Comment: Yes, to apply L'Hopital's rule, the function must be in the form $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ while satisfying the condition outlined by @NigelOvermars in the comment below

Comment: Oh, I see! thanks again.

Comment: And it must be in the form of $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.